Script to dynamically create a 3 columns per n rows from a list
I'm coding a MVC app with ASP .NET 8.0 framework and following code should retrieve a List from my controller to create a 3 columns per n rows table in my view. It run well till the last row:
tableau.appendChild(tbl);
Where I get the error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')

I didn't find a way to create my table using the foreach loop so I'm using the for loop with javascript.
@model List<ViewListTable>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function f() {
      var myArray = [];
      @foreach(var d in Model) {
        @: myArray.push("@d.Name");
      }

      var cptData = myArray.length;
      var tableau = document.getElementById('tableau');
      var tbl     = document.createElement("table");
      var x       = 0;

      for (var i = 0; i < cptData / 3; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
          var td = document.createElement('td');
          if (x < cptData) {
            var a        = document.createElement('a');
            var el_span  = document.createElement('span');
            var linkText = document.createTextNode(myArray[x]);
            var tab      = myArray[x];

            //console.log(tab);
            el_span.setAttribute('style', 'color: #07C');
            a.setAttribute('href', "'" + tab + "'");
            a.setAttribute('class', 'button');
            a.title = "Éditer les données de la table:";
            a.appendChild(linkText);
            el_span.appendChild(a);
            td.appendChild(el_span);
          };
          x += 1;
          tr.appendChild(td)
        };
        tbl.appendChild(tr);
      }
      tableau.appendChild(tbl);
    }
    f();
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="tableau"></div> 
</body>




Tableau element does not exist when script runs because html is handled top down.  Quick fix- put script after tableau element.

I had a test in my side and I added console.info(tbl);console.info(tableau); before tableau.appendChild(tbl);, then I found that tableau is null and this is the reason for the error you shared.

The solution is moving the <script> from <head> to <body>.


HTML is executed from top to bottom. So, as with other programming languages.
First of all, you are trying to get element with ID tableau defined in document:
var tableau = document.getElementById('tableau');

before  reaching:
<div id="tableau"></div>

so it returns null.
Solution is simple, move getting the element AFTER its declaration in HTML. So just move entire script element at the bottom:
<body>
    <div id="tableau"></div>
    <script>...</script>
</body>


Agree! HTML is executed from top to bottom
